# canvas flickering on chrome

Tags: performance, google-chrome, canvas, flicker

Seems like an update on google chrome messed up my canvas animation. Currently I´m getting lots of flickering, this seems awkward because I haven´t changed any of the code and it worked smoothly a couple days ago. Am I the only one with this problem?

ps: the animation works fine in firefox.

Comment: I´m using setTimeout ( enterFrame , 1 )

Comment: Did you find a way to fix it ? It seems similar to the problem I reported : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=805066

Answer (score 1):

Are you using double buffering? You should expect flickering unless you are using a buffer. See [Does HTML5/Canvas Support Double Buffering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795269/does-html5-canvas-support-double-buffering) and [Google search](http://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&site=webhp&source=hp&q=canvas%20avoid%20flickering&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=5d404a30b8bb48ee&ion=1&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=c43ae83afcd0b44f&biw=1279&bih=865&ion=1)

Comment: No, I was having a good performance without it...but seems I´ll have to implement it. thanks for the recommendation

Comment: no luck...it´s weird because i´ve been working on the canvas for about 3 months and never had this problem...I´ve tested several versions of my project that worked fine and suddenly I have flickering (on firefox things work ass expected)

Answer (score 0):

try using requestAnimationFrame: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame