# Do we need to implement double buffering ourselves with <canvas>?

Tags: html, gwt, canvas

I'm starting to use Canvas (with GWT), do we need to implement double buffering ourselves? Wondering if somehow the browsers instead implement this for us already.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You absolutely do not need to implement double buffering yourself and doing so would be a waste of time and performance.

Lucky for us every canvas implementation implements it behind-the-scenes for you.

Here's a simple example of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/HYVLj/

Comment: Yeah I was really relieved when I found out too. Thanks for asking the question so that future people wondering will find out too!

Comment: Wrong. Consider watching http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Prkyd5n0P7k, implementing it, doing your own timing tests, and decide for yourself whether it offers extra performance.

Comment: @sws is this still the case?

Comment: @FutuToad I haven't read anything recently which leads me to believe differently.

Comment: @sws Can you link to a more succinct example than a 50 minute video? It's too time-consuming to tell if your claim is true (or if the video even supports your claim at all). No live test I have seen yet has suggested that manually double-buffering a canvas increases performance in any way.

Comment: @Simon Sarris Can you provide a list of links to online tests which refute that double-buffering offers a performance increase? The video offers the timing, numbers and discussion of how it works. Apart from me re-watching the video and writing a transcript for you, this is coming from a reliable source (a Google developer) who is discussing performance gains gotten by following a particular programming paradigm which has existed since Mode 21h. Do the research yourself, and you won't be displeased with the results.

Comment: @sws — the video you link is talking about a subtly but crucially different concept entirely. In that video, they were originally doing a lot of draws of individual tiles into the canvas on every frame. Instead, they loaded all the tiles into an offscreen buffer ONCE and then copied the entire buffer on every frame. The savings didn't come from doing it offscreen, but rather drastically reducing the number of draws. In other words, it wasn't off-DOM rendering but rather *pre-rendering* that saved the day.

Comment: Hmm... Your example with squares works as expected on both desktop and mobile version of Google Chrome. But, for some reason, my app does not, although I used `requestAnimationFrame()`: [Matematika 3](http://page.dlabac.com/matematika3). You probably won't understand the language, sorry - just wait for the app to load and click on any title. The flickering of chest bitmaps will be clearly visible on mobile (even on flagship Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge), but not on the desktop version.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's quite an old thread, but I wanted to point out that the Fiddle in Simon Sarris answer seems wrong. When I tried it  on Google Chrome, I inserted an alert statement between lines 10 and 11 (just before the loop) and the square had disappeared, just to reappear after I closed the alert window. It seems that the loop is not executed correctly. Maybe javascript optimized it out. Anyway, it seems to me that no double buffering is done. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: By adding an alert, aren't you possibly giving the browser the option to draw to the canvas? Because as far as it's concerned, the script has stopped executing? I don't know precisely how alerts work with respect to yielding control back to other parts of the browser rendering sequence.