# Stop canvas flicker on re-render

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have written a jQuery plugin that will render four polygons onto a `canvas` and fill them with an image.

When you mouse over a `polygon` it is moved to a separate top layer and re-rendered so it expands and then contracts if you mouse out.

Is there any way to do this so that it doesn't flicker?

I've had a look a [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795269/does-html5-canvas-support-double-buffering) but don't quite understand what the accepted answer is doing (I know it draws the image on a seperate layer but I don't know how it checks if this has finished rendering before using it) or how to include it in [my jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/KAkvX/7/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out it was because I was making a new image object everytime I made the drawing:

```
            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.src = polyArray[4];
            imageObj.onload = function () {
                poly.setFillPatternImage(imageObj);
                stage.draw();
            }
```

I changed this so that these objects were created and cached into an array and then re-used.  This enabled the re-rendering to run a lot faster and removed the flickering:

http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/KAkvX/10/